# package android.util doesnot exit

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

I have the below java code in my Linux environment. This was not created using android studio, using a nano editor in the terminal.

```java
import android.util.Base64;
public class Simple{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  String testing = "1234";
  String testnew = Base64.encodeToString(testing.getBytes("UTF-8"),0);
  System.out.println(testnew);
}
}
```

The purpose of using a nano editor or terminal for coding is this is just a block that needs to be verified during testing of a source code. When this code was compiled using `javac test.java` it responded with the following errors.

```sh
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
test.java:2: error: class Simple is public, should be declared in a file named Simple.java
public class Simple{
       ^
test.java:1: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Base64;
                   ^
test.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    String testnewpin = Base64.encodeToString(testpin.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable Base64
  location: class Simple
3 errors
```

I have installed android-libtutils using the apt package manager. I tried compiling the above code using an online compiler and it responded with `cannot find symbol String testnewpin = Base64.encodeToString(testpin.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0);` as mentioned in errors for Linux terminal.

OS : Ubuntu

How can I solve this via terminal ? Can this be done only using Android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: You did not specify the sources of dependencies in your `javac` command. This is why, for the past 20 years or so, we have used build tools to build software. Android apps nowadays tend to be built using Gradle, and [you can build your APK from the command line using Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline).

Comment: I am not building an APK or software, I just want to compile this piece of code and get the output, how can I achieve that via terminal ?

Comment: Start by removing `import android.util.Base64` and the reference to `Base64`. You will be running this code on Linux, not Android, and so you cannot use things from the Android SDK.

Comment: that means it is not possible to compile the code in a terminal like a normal java code right?

Comment: You cannot run the code on Linux. And Android does not support `main()`, so apparently you are planning on running this on Linux.